# How do i place text over crossfading slider?

Tags: html, css

How could I place a text over the image?
When I try it just makes the text stay in one of the images.

I don't want the text to change or disappear, it has to be the same text for all the images.

I have tried to set `position` as `absolute` and place it over the image but won't show for all images just the first one.

```css
.slider {
  max-width: 1080px;
  height: 95%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 120px;
  position: relative;
}
.slide1,.slide2,.slide3 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.slide1 {
  background: url(images/child.jpg)no-repeat center;
      background-size: cover;
    animation:fade 8s infinite;
-webkit-animation:fade 8s infinite;

} 
.slide2 {
  background: url(images/tech.jpg)no-repeat center;
      background-size: cover;
    animation:fade2 8s infinite;
-webkit-animation:fade2 8s infinite;
}
.slide3 {
    background: url(http://media.dunkedcdn.com/assets/prod/40946/580x0-9_cropped_1371564896_p17tbq6n86jdo3ishhta3fv1i3.jpg)no-repeat center;
      background-size: cover;
    animation:fade3 8s infinite;
-webkit-animation:fade3 8s infinite;
}
@keyframes fade
{
  0%   {opacity:1}
  33.333% { opacity: 0}
  66.666% { opacity: 0}
  100% { opacity: 1}
}
@keyframes fade2
{
  0%   {opacity:0}
  33.333% { opacity: 1}
  66.666% { opacity: 0 }
  100% { opacity: 0}
}
@keyframes fade3
{
  0%   {opacity:0}
  33.333% { opacity: 0}
  66.666% { opacity: 1}
  100% { opacity: 0}
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide1"></div>
  <div class="slide2"></div>
  <div class="slide3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: where exactly is the text you are referring to, in your current code?

Comment: Is that what you need? - https://codverter.com/src/webeditor?query=bfe5d3ea-6b79-4c64-b07a-8267a999684e

Answer (score 0):

Add an element, position it `absolute` also, and give it a bigger `z-index` than that of the images.

```css
.slider {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1080px;
  height: 95vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 120px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider-text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0 z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slider-text"> My text </div>
  <div class="slide1"></div>
  <div class="slide2"></div>
  <div class="slide3"></div>
</div>
```

Change the left/top properties to reposition it.

Comment: When i do this my text goes on the top of the website not even close to my image :/

Comment: it shouldn't. your slider has `position: relative`, and the `slider-text` should be positioned in relation to it. You might want to try setting the slider's height to `height: 95vh;` instead of 95%, which will not take effect if it doesn't have a parent with a specified height. In this case, your images might overflow the container - to check this, add `overflow: hidden` to your slider, in order to see what it's actual dimensions are. Add these: `.slider{ height: 95vh; overflow: hidden; }`